# Expected a HTTP 302 but get a HTTP 301 using NodeJS http client

Tags: http, node.js, github

I have this NodeJS snippnet :

```
require('http').get({
    secure: true,
    host: 'github.com',
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/downloads/Graylog2/graylog2-web-interface/graylog2-web-interface-0.9.6.tar.gz',
    'headers': {
        Host: 'github.com'
    }}).on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

It is suppose to do a simple GET request on https://github.com/downloads/Graylog2/graylog2-web-interface/graylog2-web-interface-0.9.6.tar.gz (sample)

The problem I face is the HTTP status, using the NodeJS client I have **301 Moved Permanently**. I am expected a **302 Found** (actually what I get with Chrome, cUrl, http://web-sniffer.net,...).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `secure` option for request. What you want is to instead use the `https` module.

```
require('https')
```